# How to mock a function inside a function python test?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have these files:

utils.py

```
def generateCode():
    while(True):
        # https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122.html
        uuid_code = str(uuid.uuid4().int)[:6]
        return uuid_code
```

generate.py

```
from utils import generateCode

def create_auth_challenge():
   code = generateCode()
   return code
```

test.py

```
from unittest.mock import patch
from generate import create_auth_challenge

@patch('utils.generateCode', return_value='123456')
def test_create_auth_challenge(self, mock_generateCode):
   answer = create_auth_challenge()
   self.assertEqual(answer,'123456')
```

but the problem is the result of the test is failed because of

> answer!='123456'

so, I think it is because the mocking process is wrong because the answer value is always a random number. What makes it wrong? Does it because of the uuid4? How to do the right mocking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you even patched `utils.generateCode`, the file **generate.py** already has imported the original `utils.generateCode` and assigned it locally as `generateCode`, thus the updated patch doesn't reflect.

### Solution 1

Instead, mock the local version of `generateCode` within **generate.py**. So change this in your **test.py**:

```
@patch('utils.generateCode', return_value='123456')
```

To:

```
@patch('generate.generateCode', return_value='123456')
```

### Solution 2

If you wish to retain patching the source `utils.generateCode`, then import the file **generate.py** only after the patch has taken effect. So change your **test.py** to:

```
...
# from generate import create_auth_challenge  # Remove this import
...
@patch('utils.generateCode', return_value='123456')
def test_create_auth_challenge(mock_generateCode):
    from generate import create_auth_challenge  # Move the import here
    ...
...
```

### Solution 3

You can also change the **generate.py** to also use it from the source `utils`. So change your **generate.py** to:

```
import utils

def create_auth_challenge():
   code = utils.generateCode()
   return code
```